# Finding the closest ground pixel on an irregular grid for given coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-xarray, satellite

I work with satellite data organised on an irregular two-dimensional grid whose dimensions are scanline (along track dimension) and ground pixel (across track dimension). Latitude and longitude information for each ground pixel are stored in auxiliary coordinate variables.

Given a (lat, lon) point, I would like to identify the closest ground pixel on my set of data.

Let's build a 10x10 toy data set:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

lon, lat = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-20, 20, 10), 
                       np.linspace(30, 60, 10))
lon += lat/10
lat += lon/10
da = xr.DataArray(data = np.random.normal(0,1,100).reshape(10,10), 
                  dims=['scanline', 'ground_pixel'],
                  coords = {'lat': (('scanline', 'ground_pixel'), lat),
                            'lon': (('scanline', 'ground_pixel'), lon)})

ax = plt.subplot(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
da.plot.pcolormesh('lon', 'lat', ax=ax, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('Blues'), 
                   infer_intervals=True);
ax.scatter(lon, lat, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines()
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: europe]

Note that the lat/lon coordinates identify the centre pixel and the pixel boundaries are automatically inferred by xarray.

Now, say I want to identify the closest ground pixel to Rome.

The best way I came up with so far is to use a scipy's kdtree on a stacked flattened lat/lon array:

```
from scipy import spatial
pixel_center_points = np.stack((da.lat.values.flatten(), da.lon.values.flatten()), axis=-1)
tree = spatial.KDTree(pixel_center_points)

rome = (41.9028, 12.4964)
distance, index = tree.query(rome)
print(index)
# 36
```

I have then to apply `unravel_index` to get my scanline/ground_pixel indexes:

```
pixel_coords = np.unravel_index(index, da.shape)
print(pixel_coords)
# (3, 6)
```

Which gives me the scanline/ground_pixel coordinates of the (supposedly) closest ground pixel to Rome:

```
ax = plt.subplot(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
da.plot.pcolormesh('lon', 'lat', ax=ax, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('Blues'), 
                   infer_intervals=True);
ax.scatter(da.lon[pixel_coords], da.lat[pixel_coords], 
           marker='x', color='r', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines()
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

I'm convinced there must me a much more elegant way to approach this problem. In particular, I would like to get rid of the flattening/unraveling steps (all my attempts to build a kdtree on a two-dimensional array failed miserably), and make use of my xarray dataset's variables as much as possible (adding a new centre_pixel dimension for example, and using it as input to `KDTree`).

Answer (score 6):

I am going to answer my own question as I believe I came up with a decent solution, which is discussed at much greater length on my [blog post](http://notes.stefanomattia.net/2017/12/12/The-quest-to-find-the-closest-ground-pixel/) on this subject.

#### Geographical distance

First of all, defining the distance between two points on the earth's surface as simply the euclidean distance between the two lat/lon pairs could lead to inaccurate results depending on the distance between two points. It is thus better to transform the coordinates to [ECEF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECEF) coordinates first and built a KD-Tree on the transformed coordinates. Assuming points on the surface of the planet (h=0) the coordinate transformation is done as such:

```
def transform_coordinates(coords):
    """ Transform coordinates from geodetic to cartesian

    Keyword arguments:
    coords - a set of lan/lon coordinates (e.g. a tuple or 
             an array of tuples)
    """
    # WGS 84 reference coordinate system parameters
    A = 6378.137 # major axis [km]   
    E2 = 6.69437999014e-3 # eccentricity squared    

    coords = np.asarray(coords).astype(np.float)

    # is coords a tuple? Convert it to an one-element array of tuples
    if coords.ndim == 1:
        coords = np.array([coords])

    # convert to radiants
    lat_rad = np.radians(coords[:,0])
    lon_rad = np.radians(coords[:,1]) 

    # convert to cartesian coordinates
    r_n = A / (np.sqrt(1 - E2 * (np.sin(lat_rad) ** 2)))
    x = r_n * np.cos(lat_rad) * np.cos(lon_rad)
    y = r_n * np.cos(lat_rad) * np.sin(lon_rad)
    z = r_n * (1 - E2) * np.sin(lat_rad)

    return np.column_stack((x, y, z))
```

#### Building the KD-Tree

We could then build the KD-Tree by transforming our dataset coordinates, taking care of flattening the 2D grid to a one-dimensional sequence of lat/lon tuples. This is because the KD-Tree input data needs to be (N,K), where N is the number of point and K is the dimensionality (K=2 in our case, as we assume no heigth component).

```
# reshape and stack coordinates
coords = np.column_stack((da.lat.values.ravel(),
                          da.lon.values.ravel()))

# construct KD-tree
ground_pixel_tree = spatial.cKDTree(transform_coordinates(coords))
```

#### Querying the tree and indexing the xarray dataset

Querying the tree is now as simple as transforming our point's lat/lon coordinates to ECEF and passing those to the tree's `query` method:

```
rome = (41.9028, 12.4964)
index = ground_pixel_tree.query(transform_coordinates(rome))
```

In doing so though, we need to unravel our index on the original dataset's shape, to get the scanline/ground_pixel indexes:

```
index = np.unravel_index(index, self.shape)
```

We could now use the two components to index our original xarray dataset, but we could also build two indexers to use with xarray [pointwise indexing](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html#more-advanced-indexing) feature:

```
index = xr.DataArray(index[0], dims='pixel'), \
        xr.DataArray(index[1], dims='pixel')
```

Getting the closest pixel is now easy and elegant at the same time:

```
da[index]
```

Note that we could also query more than one point at once, and by building the indexers as above, we could still index the dataset with a single call:

```
da[index]
```

Which would then return a subset of the dataset containing the closest ground pixels to our query points.

#### Further readings

- Using the euclidean norm on the lat/lon tuples could be accurate enough for smaller distance (thing of it as approximating the earth as flat, it works on a small scale). More details on geographic distances [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance).
- Using a KD-Tree to find the nearest neighbour is not the only way to address this problem, see this very comprehensive [article](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/blogs/developer/en/entry/accessing_netcdf_data_by_coordinates).
- An implementation of KD-Tree directly into xarray [is in the pipeline](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/475#issuecomment-125468579).
- My [blog post](http://notes.stefanomattia.net/2017/12/12/The-quest-to-find-the-closest-ground-pixel/) on the subject.

Comment: As you've noted, this feature is within xarray's scope but is just waiting for an interested user/developer to implement it. It looks like you're well on your way to making that happen. I encourage you to submit a PR to the xarray project if you'd like to see this feature in the package.